# Create CouchBase FTS from application

Tags: full-text-search, couchbase

Is there a way to create `CouchBase FTS` from an application?

The only way I could find in official documentation, is to create it manually from the web ui, but I need to do it from my application code.

Preferably from SDK (.net/C#), or at least by posting *FTS definition* to some url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean an FTS index? If so, yes, you can definitely use the REST API to create indexes. I wrote a [blog post on doing exactly that](https://blog.couchbase.com/powershell-couchbase-rest-api/) (I used Powershell, but the principle is the same).

The REST endpoint you use is a PUT to: couchbase:8094/api/index/your-index-name

In fact, if you look at the FTS UI, it should generate a cURL command for you. The [Full Text Search API documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/rest-api/rest-fts.html) has all the details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can not run this, `405 Method Not Allowed` is returned. also given only server address (x:8091) where to get this (x:8094) end point.

Comment: Ports 8091-8094 should all be open (among others). You only have port 8091 access?

Comment: Aren't this ports configurable?! if user has changed ports on installation and I know only main port, is there an api to get url for creating fts? And any idea why I get `405 Method not allowed` result? (I use `Administrator` username and password)

Comment: The ports are not configurable, as far as I know. You could potentially put a proxy in front of them, but all the clients expect certain port numbers. I think you're getting the error message because you're using the wrong port.

Comment: it appears that `"uuid": "30b327932bc52448"` must be removed from auto created index definition json.